# How to set application variable in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I'm using angular 6 where we can create multiple applications and libraries apart from default app.module. I want to use an application variable like a url prefix or cache expiry time which can be used in all libraries and applications. But when i declare a variable in environment.ts i can only refer it in it's root directory that is src folder. since other projects where i want to refer to this variable, are not created in its root directory, it throws error at runtime saying it cannot access variables from folders not declared in it's root directory.

Can you please suggest something which can help me get access to application variable  across all application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally.

I created a folder Config at the root level and added a file environment.ts.
I copied the environment variables from src/app/environment/environment.ts into Config/environment.ts but with different values.

Eg. in src/app/environment/environment.ts
i added a variable setTimeout=3000

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   setTimout=3000
 };
```

and in Config/environment.ts setTimeout=13000

```
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   setTimout=13000
 };
```

in app.component.ts i used this setTimeout variable.

```
 constructor(){
    console.log("timeout is "+environment.setTimeout);
 }
```

I ran it in dev env and it consoled 3000.

Now i replaced the folowwing line in angular.json

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
```

with

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "Config/environment.ts"
            }
          ]
```

Then i ran   **ng serve [MyAppName] --prod** .

And went to dist/myapp folder and ran lite-server to deploy and run app locally.
And my setTimeout value from config/environment.ts replaced the one used during development in app.component.ts from environment/environment.ts file. It consoled 13000.

So in this way i can create a config like folder and use it in any library or app.